# Jqgrid Custom Validation Not Working in mvc3

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

My Code :
Custom Validation function error pls help >>>>

Custom Validation Function can't return a value,json function is still working but it could not return a value

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

$.getJSON("/ChequeBookReceipt/getChequeType/", function (data) {
            setupGrid(data.item);
        });





        function reload(result) {
            $("#listChequeBook").trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
    });



    function setupGrid(data) {
        var success = false;
        var message = 'success';
        var item = data;
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            /*Begin Grid*/
            $("#listChequeBook").jqGrid({
                url: '/ChequeBookReceipt/GetChequeBookGrid/',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                colNames: ['Cheque Type', 'Book number', 'First Leaf Number', 'Last Leaf Number'],

                colModel: [

                         { name: 'chequeType', index: 'chequeType', editrules: { required: true }, width: 150, editable: true, sortable: false, sorttype: "text", edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: item }, formatter: "select", width: "200px" },
                         { name: 'bookNumber', index: 'bookNumber',
                             editrules: { integer: true, required: true, custom: true,
                                 custom_func: function (value, colname) {

                                     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                                     $.getJSON("/ChequeBookReceipt/IsUniqueBookNumber/", { value: value, colname: colname }, function (data) {

                                         if (data != null) {
                                             //alert(data.success + " - " + data.message);
                                              return [data.success, data.message];


                                         }

                                     });




                                 }
                             }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' }, sortable: false, width: 100, editable: true, sorttype: "text", width: "100px"
                         },
                         { name: 'firstLeafNumber', index: 'firstLeafNumber', editrules: { integer: true, required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' }, sortable: false, width: 100, editable: true, sorttype: "text", width: "100px" },
                         { name: 'lastLeafNumber', index: 'lastLeafNumber', editrules: { integer: true, required: true}, sortable: false, width: 100, editable: true, sorttype: "text", width: "100px" }


                    ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                //     loadonce: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                autowidth: true,
                sortname: 'bookNumber',
                sortorder: "asc",
                pager: jQuery('#pagerChequeBook'),
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "Cheque Book",
                editurl: "/ChequeBookReceipt/UpdateChequeBookGrid/",
                //                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                //                    if (id && id !== "") {
                //                        jQuery('#listChequeBook').editRow(id, true);
                //                    
                //                    }
                //                },
                beforeRequest: function () {
                    $.getJSON("/ChequeBookReceipt/getChequeType/", function (data) {
                        item = data.item;

                        // setupGrid(data.item);
                    });
                }


            });
            jQuery("#listChequeBook").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pagerChequeBook", { edit: false, add: false, del: true, search: false, refresh: false },
             { reloadAfterSubmit: true });
            $("#listChequeBook").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pagerChequeBook', { addParams: { addRowParams: {
                "keys": true, "aftersavefunc": function () { var grid = $("#listChequeBook"); reloadgrid(grid); }
            }
            }, editParams: { "aftersavefunc": function () { var grid = $("#listChequeBook"); reloadgrid(grid); } }


            });


            function reloadgrid(grid) {
                //   grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
                grid.setGridParam({ datatype: 'json', page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
            }

            /*End Grid*/


        });
    }

</script>
```

Custom Validation function error  pls help

please help

Comment: can you tell me what exactly error is coming?